# Why can't I use an implementing class as an argument in another interface if the first interface defines it?

Tags: java

I have two interfaces. The first:

```
public interface IGoable {
     int go();
}
```

the second uses the first interface as an argument type in it's method definition:

```
public interface IMove {
    int move(IGoable goThisMany);
}
```

I have a class that implements the IGoable interface:

```
public class ImplGoable implements IGoable {
    @Override
    public int go() {
        return 0;
    }

    public int dumby() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Here's the problem. I implement the IMove interface in a class and try to use the ImplGoable class as an argument in the implemented move() method like so:

```
public class TestGoThere implements IMove {

    @Override
    public int move(ImplGoable goImp) {
        return goImp.go();
    }

}
```

It gives me the following error:

> The method move(ImplGoable) of type TestGoThere must override or
>   implement a supertype method

To avoid the error, I have to use the IGoable interface as a type for the argument in the implemented method like so:

```
public class TestGoThere implements IMove {

    @Override
    public int move(IGoable goImp) {
        return goImp.go();
    }

}
```

Why am I not able to use the ImplGoable class since it implements the IGoable interface?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the `ImplGoable` inplace of `IGoable` because in your declaration you have setup  a contract with `IGoable` interface only.`ImplGoable` will implement and override the interface method but there is no stopping it from adding new methods.
Because of your contract only methods you can use are the ones defined in your interface i.e `go()`.Therefore you can use `goImp` object but within the range of its contract only
this  means that object can be any valid objects implementing the interface but the type needs to be `IGoable` only

Answer (score 1):

You could work around this with generics (although whether or not you would want to would entirely depend on your use case).

If you change the definition of your interface IMove to be:

```
public interface IMove<T extends IGoable> {
    int move(T goThisMany);
}
```

This then allows you to define the concrete implementation in the class that implement the interface i.e.:

```
public class TestGoThere implements IMove<ImplGoable> {

    @Override
    public int move(ImplGoable goImp) {
        return goImp.go();
    }

}
```

and allows you to use ImplGoable as the argument parameter type.
As I said, whether or not you would want to do this is an entirely different matter and really depends what you are trying to do.
There's some good reading [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) about generics.